# About Angular list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a list using Angular, where the data (say like over 1000 items) is retrieved from the server using JSON call. In my plan, the list will only show x amount of items in the list, and will load x more items into it when the user pull up the list.

So my question here is, how to write the expression for the ng-repeat so that

- It will only show x amount of items when first loading the list
- It will only load x amount of items when user pulled up the list

I think i read somewhere about ngRepeat being able to do this kind of feature, to limit and control the amount of items shown or loaded onto the list, but i forgot where i read it.

But someone told me that better way of doing this is by limiting the amount of data retrieved when using JSON call rather than letting Angular do it.

So i'm kind of confuse in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at ngInfiniteScroll http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/.

Last fall, i want to use a similar solution and ended up there.

Comment: Nice! I'll try look into this. Thanks